CredentialProvider is not found in the Android app and after migration getting com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Cognito Identity not configured
I am trying to update the deprecated methods of the AWSMobilClient credential provider is deprecated.
Error:
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Cognito Identity not configure  
                       at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getCredentials(AWSMobileClient.java:392)                                      
at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$1.run(AWSMobileClient.java:445)                      
at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$1.run(AWSMobileClient.java:442)                          
at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.ReturningRunnable.await(ReturningRunnable.java:31)                  
at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient.getAWSCredentials(AWSMobileClient.java:433)

I have used this in the root Application() kt file as below
override fun onCreate() {
         super.onCreate()

     AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentialsProvider = object : AWSCredentialsProvider {
                override fun getCredentials(): AWSCredentials {
                    return object : AWSCredentials {
                        override fun getAWSAccessKeyId(): String {
                            return getString(R.string.access_key)
                        }
    
                        override fun getAWSSecretKey(): String {
                            return getString(R.string.secret_key)
                        }
                    }
                }
                override fun refresh() {}
            }
}

To
var customCredentialsProvider = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().credentials
override fun onCreate() {
         super.onCreate()

customCredentialsProvider = object : AWSCredentialsProvider, AWSCredentials {
             override fun getCredentials(): AWSCredentials {
                     // Return your custom AWSCredentials implementation
                     return object : AWSCredentials {
                         override fun getAWSAccessKeyId(): String {
                             // Return your access key
                             return getString(R.string.access_key)
                         }
 override fun getAWSSecretKey(): String {
                             // Return your secret key
                             return getString(R.string.secret_key)
                         }
                 }
             }
 
             override fun getAWSAccessKeyId(): String {
                 return getString(R.string.access_key)
             }
 
             override fun getAWSSecretKey(): String {
                 return getString(R.string.secret_key)
             }

             override fun refresh() {

             }
         }
 }

